# Block port with dual response

Tags: port, service, block

Theoretically, could I block a service running on port x by starting some other service on x with it? Would it return two responses or one big mixed response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't. You can only bind one service/process to a given port at the same time.

Comment: So will the OS stop you?

Comment: Yes, it will tell you something like "Port x is already in use".